# Query a single document from Firestore in Flutter (cloud_firestore Plugin)

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, querying

*Edit: This Question is outdated, and I am sure, new documentation and more recent answers are available as of now.*

I want to retrieve data of only a **single document** via its ID. My approach with example data of:

```
TESTID1 {
     'name': 'example', 
     'data': 'sample data',
}
```

was something like this:

```
Firestore.instance.document('TESTID1').get() => then(function(document) {
    print(document('name'));
}
```

but that does not seem to be correct syntax.

I was not able to find *any detailed documentation on querying firestore* within flutter (dart) since the firebase documentation only addresses Native WEB, iOS, Android etc. but not Flutter. The documentation of cloud_firestore is also way too short. There is only one example that shows how to query multiple documents into a stream which is not what i want to do.

Related issue on missing documentation:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14324

It can't be that hard to get data from a single document.

UPDATE:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION').document('ID')
.get().then((DocumentSnapshot) =>
      print(DocumentSnapshot.data['key'].toString());
);
```

is not executed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Null safe code (Recommended)

You can either query the document in a function (for example on press of a button) or inside a widget (like a `FutureBuilder`).

- **In a method:** (one time listen)

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  var docSnapshot = await collection.doc('doc_id').get();
  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic>? data = docSnapshot.data();
    var value = data?['some_field']; // <-- The value you want to retrieve. 
    // Call setState if needed.
  }
  ```
- **In a `FutureBuilder`** (one time listen)

  ```dart
  FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    future: collection.doc('doc_id').get(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text ('Error = ${snapshot.error}');

      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        var data = snapshot.data!.data();
        var value = data!['some_field']; // <-- Your value
        return Text('Value = $value');
      }

      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  )
  ```
- **In a `StreamBuilder`:** (always listening)

  ```dart
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: collection.doc('doc_id').snapshots(),
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');

      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        var output = snapshot.data!.data();
        var value = output!['some_field']; // <-- Your value
        return Text('Value = $value');
      }

      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  )
  ```

Comment: Can we get the subcollection along with the document by any of these methods?

Comment: what should i return if docSnapsot does not exist?

Answer (score 91):

> but that does not seem to be the correct syntax.

It is not the correct syntax because you are missing a `collection()` call. To solve this, you should use something like this:

```
var document = await Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').document('TESTID1');
document.get() => then(function(document) {
    print(document("name"));
});
```

Or in more simpler way:

```
var document = await Firestore.instance.document('COLLECTION_NAME/TESTID1');
document.get() => then(function(document) {
    print(document("name"));
});
```

If you want to get data in realtime, please use the following code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION_NAME').document('TESTID1').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return new Text("Loading");
        }
        var userDocument = snapshot.data;
        return new Text(userDocument["name"]);
      }
  );
}
```

It will help you set also the name to a text view.

Comment: The error you pointed out is true but is not the main problem.
According to AndroidStudio: `the getter for DocumentReference is not defined`.
So `document().get()` is invalid as well. I find there is a lack of information on the basic syntax of these queries. I have even read the [specification](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_firestore)

Comment: You should also use `await`. Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: I did vote +1, but it will only appear publicly when i earn enough reputation..
**Is there any documentation or resource on this, you can recommend?**

Comment: Regarding Firebase, official docs. Regarding Firebase and Flutter I don't know.

Comment: I tried the realtime stream and I get this error `The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>'.`. Any idea ?

Comment: @ThéoChampion Please post another question for that problem with its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: there are some typos in the code arent they? document('name') should be document['name'] as far as i understand how documents work with firestore

Comment: if I try to pass `userDocument` to a new page as an argument I cannot do `userDocument["name"]` on the second page. I get an error because `name` doesn't exist (but it's `Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'`)

Comment: @Dani Without seeing your code, I cannot be much of a help. So please post another fresh question, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: It's exactly the same as the code above van sending the params instead: `var userDocument = snapshot.data; Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                '/my-set',
                                arguments: userDocument
                              );`

Comment: got it. Passing now `userDocument.dat`, which is the actual map (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721694/convert-firestore-documentsnapshot-to-map-in-flutter)

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo , you answer is helpful .. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexMamo for me I am getting this question issue with Builder.
can you look into my gist. I have attached code output. and printed document.
https://gist.github.com/surapuramakhil/5dbbc060c92557c18ecab6e2dc9b9cbd

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram You should post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I believe "Firestore.instance..." has been deprecated in favor of "FirebaseFirestore.instance..." per documentation at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#firestore

Answer (score 27):

If you want to use a where clause

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('collection_name').where(
    FieldPath.documentId,
    isEqualTo: "some_id"
).getDocuments().then((event) {
    if (event.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        Map<String, dynamic> documentData = event.documents.single.data; //if it is a single document
    }
}).catchError((e) => print("error fetching data: $e"));
```

Comment: I was looking for this

Comment: how to use it later to get value from the fetched document?

Comment: @Harsh Jhunjhunuwala You can use it as a Map.
Eg: if you want to retrieve a field called name from the document,
var name = documentData["name"];

Comment: it says 
"A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>"

Comment: can this be cast to custom model?

Answer (score 13):

This is simple you can use a DOCUMENT SNAPSHOT

```
DocumentSnapshot variable = await Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION NAME').document('DOCUMENT ID').get();
```

You can access its data using `variable.data['FEILD_NAME']`

Comment: I can't "the operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'. "

Comment: To access the data you must write variable.data()['FIELD_NAME']. I had the same problem and the () was missing.

Answer (score 7):

Update FirebaseFirestore 12/2021

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('YOUR COLLECTION NAME')
              .doc(id) //ID OF DOCUMENT
              .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return new CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        var document = snapshot.data;
        return new Text(document["name"]);
     }
  );
}
```

Comment: How can you take out a certain piece of information using this?
Lets Say my collection is books
Document is Harry Potter
And under that i have table with Title Author Description, how would i print the author?

Comment: Widget _buildBookItem(BuildContext context, int index, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    final doc = snapshot.data.docs[index];
    return Text(print(doc.author));
};

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me in 2021

```
      var userPhotos;
      Future<void> getPhoto(id) async {
        //query the user photo
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(id).snapshots().listen((event) {
          setState(() {
            userPhotos = event.get("photoUrl");
            print(userPhotos);
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Is this a Future Query or a Stream Query? The return is a Future, but isn't the snapshots query for Stream? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code when you just want to fetch a document from firestore collection , to perform some operations on it, and not to display it using some widget  (updated jan 2022 )

```
   fetchDoc() async {

   // enter here the path , from where you want to fetch the doc
   DocumentSnapshot pathData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('ProfileData')
       .doc(currentUser.uid)
       .get();

   if (pathData.exists) {
     Map<String, dynamic>? fetchDoc = pathData.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
     
     //Now use fetchDoc?['KEY_names'], to access the data from firestore, to perform operations , for eg
     controllerName.text = fetchDoc?['userName']


     // setState(() {});  // use only if needed
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple way :**

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('YOUR COLLECTION NAME')
              .doc(id) //ID OF DOCUMENT
              .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return new CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        var document = snapshot.data;
        return new Text(document["name"]);
     }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var  document = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc('CXvGTxT49NUoKi9gRt96ltvljz42').get();
        Map<String,dynamic>? value = document.data();
        print(value!['userId']);
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help users understand how this answers the question

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Firestore document by following code:

```
future FirebaseDocument() async{

    var variable = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Collection_name').doc('Document_Id').get();
    print(variable['field_name']); 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this simple code:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").document().setData({
   "name":"Majeed Ahmed"
});
```