# Flutter error The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create some charts in a flutter, I am getting stuck in DocumentSnapshot.data I feel like flutter has changed the naming but I can not find it anywhere.

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sales').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return LinearProgressIndicator();
        } else {
  
          List<Sales> sales = snapshot.data.docs
              .map((documentSnapshot) => Sales.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot.data))
              .toList();
          return _buildChart(context, sales);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Maybe the answer to this question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721694/convert-firestore-documentsnapshot-to-map-in-flutter i.e. use documentSnapshot.data.data to get a map of data

Comment: Also, there is possibly a typo in Sales.fromMap(DocumentSnapshot.data) since you seem to be using the classname instead of the instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accoring to the [FlutterFire API docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots) the `data` member of class `DocumentSnapshot` is a function returning a map; so it needs to be called to return the snapshot's data in a map:

```
       List<Sales> sales = snapshot.data.docs
          .map((shapshot) => Sales.fromMap(snapshot.data()))
          .toList();
```

Note that I changed the parameter name to `snapshot` to make code more readable and avoid accidental use of the classname.

Comment: Thank you Ber, it works fine! I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
          StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .document(id)
                      .collection('chatWith')
                      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                      .snapshots(),

                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                              AppColor.colorCustom),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      if (snapshot.data.documents.length == 0) {
                        return Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            "No Chat History Found",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize:
                                  Util.px_23 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                            ),
                            softWrap: true,
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                              Util.px_10 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _listItem(
                              context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                )
```

I implemented like this to retrieve data for my chat application. I think that code is useful to you. Try it