# How to Convert Dart Snapshot object data to String Variables from Flutter Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am Performing CRUD operations with Flutter Firestore. Here i want to Read data from Firestore i have a Peace of  code here.

```
      var noteInfo = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()!;
      String docID = snapshot.data!.docs[index].id;
      print(noteInfo.toString());
```

here `noteInfo` contains Following data

```
{description: My Name is Qasim, title: Qasim}
```

Now i have two String Variables `Name` where i want to store title attribute of `noteInfo` and `des` where i want to store description attribute of object `noteInfo`. Data from Firestore is fetched. I just want to store these two attributes in seprate string variables.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in your code, `noteInfo` is a `Map`. So you can get the values for those two variables with:

```
var title = noteInfo["title"];
var description = noteInfo["description"]
```

---

To get the data as a map, use:

```
var noteInfo = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()! as Map;
```

Also see: [Convert Firestore DocumentSnapshot to Map in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721694/convert-firestore-documentsnapshot-to-map-in-flutter)

Comment: the Operator '[]' is not defined for the type object in dart  and  'noteInfo' is an object so i am unable to use this operator '[]' with 'noteInfo' variable.

Comment: I added some more info for that, mostly found by searching for the error message you now posted.

Comment: problem solved! thanks