# Flutter: futurebuilder of firestore documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the documents of a few users (in my collection: users).
I stored all the ID's that I want in a list.

```
List shortIDList = [12345, 23425, 32453]
```

I'm trying this function to get the users from the shortIDList.

```
 shortIDList.forEach((element) => getFirestoreUsers(st: element));

 getFirestoreUsers({String st}) async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document('$st')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      print(ds.data);
   // I would like to add all these documents to a futurebuilder
    });
  }
```

I would like to add all the documents (to a new list?) That I can use in a futurebuilder, to display all the user information example: profile picture, name etc...

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

You can add it to a list.

```
 myList.add(ds.data);
```

But you have to define the list:

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> myList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

Then it's possible to use it in a futureBuilder

Answer (score 1):

you are using a list but data is saved by json 
try using this json format 
for more see this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517382/query-a-single-document-from-firestore-in-flutter-cloud-firestore-plugin)