# How to make a one-time simple query with Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Dart/Flutter and learning Firebase Firestore... I'm using the following method to test before creating UI:

```
_testFireStore() async {
  var result = Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: 'IvBEiD990Vh0D9t24l2GCCdsrAf1')
      .snapshots();

  await for (var snapshot in result) {
    for (var user in snapshot.documents) {
      print('main.DEBUG: ' + user.data.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

It works as expected -- the print statement is executed initially,  *but also subsequently in real-time every time any field is updated in the document in the Firestore database*.

How can this code be changed such that the snapshot is only retrieved once -- not "subscribed/listened" to... and thus we don't waste bandwidth on unwanted/unneeded data and the print statement is only executed once?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I think both answers work, but Doug's was first.

Comment: For more Answers, visit my (older) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517382/query-a-single-document-from-firestore-in-flutter-cloud-firestore-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Firestore.instance.collection(...).where(...)` returns a [Query](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html) object.  It has a method called [getDocuments()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html) that executes the query and gives you a Future with a single set of results.

```
var query = Firestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: 'IvBEiD990Vh0D9t24l2GCCdsrAf1');
query.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    // handle the results here
})
```

Or use `await` to get the QuerySnapshot, since `getDocumets()` returns a Future.

Comment: I tried putting a print statement where the ' // handle ' comment is but it is never executed.  also tried putting 'await' prior to query.getDoc... but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDocuments()`, to retrieve all the documents once:

```
_testFireStore() async {
  var result = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: 'IvBEiD990Vh0D9t24l2GCCdsrAf1')
      .getDocuments();
      print(result.documents.toString());
}
```