# Firebase Firstore subcollection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

please how can I get all the value of my `IndividualTaxData` subcollection in Flutter.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried that isn't working the way you expect.  I suggest starting with the documentation.  https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Answer (score 0):

First, you must get the reference to the parent document:

```dart
DocumentReference parentRef = Firestore.intances.collection('TaxData').document(taxDataId);
```

You can do the previous part with a direct reference to the document (like the code above) or with a query. Later, you must get the reference of the subcollection and the document that you get the information:

```dart
DocumentReference subRef = parentRef.collection('IndividualTaxData').document(individualTaxId);
```

And finally, get the data:

```
DocumentSnapshot docSnap = await subRef.get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  but what's the purpose of the parent reference I didn't see it being used anywhere in your code

Comment: the error was from my path... thank you very much, but I have to ask why use document reference instead of collection reference

Answer (score 0):

For you to return a simple document, you can use the following code for it.

```
var document = await Firestore.instance.collection('IndividualTaxData').document('<document_name>');
document.get() => then(function(document) {
    print(document('character'));
    // you can print other fields from your document
}
```

With the above code, you will reference your collection `IndividualTaxData` and then load it's data to a variable that you can print the values.

In case you want to retrieve all the documents from your collection, you can start using the below code.

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('IndividualTaxData').getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;

documents.forEach((data) => print(data));
// This print is just an example of it.
```

With this, you will load all your documents into a list that you iterate and print after - or that you can use with another method.

In addition to that, as future references, I would recommend you to check the following links as well.

- [Query a single document from Firestore in Flutter (cloud_firestore Plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517382/query-a-single-document-from-firestore-in-flutter-cloud-firestore-plugin)
- [How to use Cloud Firestore with Flutter](https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27)

Le me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thank you, but I wish to query multiple documents

Comment: Hi @nonsoedu I have updated my answer, based on your comment.

Comment: thanks again, I will try this... just to be sure... will this work for subcollection

Comment: thank you very much I used the flutter cloud_firestore class, CollectionReference class to store my query I think it did most of the heavy lifting for me...

Comment: That's great @nonsoedu ! If you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it or upvoting it.