# How can i get data from firebase by document ID in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So, i have a **document id** as you seen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbpIn.png)

and i want to get data from firebase **according to document id.**

i dont know how can i do that.

My firebase path is also like this:

```
 final CollectionReference productCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('product')
      .doc('$newRoomname')
      .collection('roomName');
```

Also i getting data like this

```
 StreamBuilder(
          stream: _databaseService.productCollection.orderBy(docID).snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor:
                      new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colorsx.mainColor),
                ),
              );
            }

            return Column(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map((documentSnapshot) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        height: context.dynamicHeight(0.2),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Lottie.asset('assets/images/4.json'))),
                    LabelText(documentSnapshot["productStatus"] ?? ""),
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
```

it's not working. is there any solution to this? i couldn't find :/

Comment: is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/63736519/4712391

Comment: Is there really any difference in getting data from Firebase by ID in Flutter and not in Flutter (for example, from another application written in Dart)?

Comment: The answers @TinusJackson pointed out contain the answer. Also see https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#documentsnapshot

Comment: appreciate sir. It's closed.